# How align a Button to Center, or Left, or Right on position below a Panel?

Tags: delphi

I want know how align a `Button` to **Center**, or on extreme **Left**, or on extreme **Right** on position below a `Panel`.

My trouble is that every time when `Form` is resized the `Button` never stays on same position.

Eg =>

- Form maximized:

[image]

- Form with real size (when is opened):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimum DFM so we can test real problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the forms `OnResize` event, after the panels repositioning, align the button to the panel with one of the following:

```
//  Button1.Left := Panel1.Left; // left
//  Button1.Left := Panel1.Left + Panel1.Width div 2 - Button1.Width div 2; // middle
//  Button1.Left := Panel1.Left + Panel1.Width - Button1.Width; // right
```

Comment: for some reason this button1 will almost appear in center, but not 100%. there is a slight offset from top and slight offset from left. I guess this comes from the borders or the menu. I am trying to use the TRelativePanel as suggested below.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [TRelativePanel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXCtrls.TRelativePanel) as a layout component. First, put your panel `upperPanel` in it. Set the `AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel` and `AlignTopWithPanel` to `True`. Then, drop your button in there and set `Below` and `AlignRightWith` both to  `upperPanel`.[image: It looks like this]

More info:
[Using the Relative Panel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_the_Relative_Panel)

The DFM (shortened for convenience) looks somehow like this:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  object RelativePanel1: TRelativePanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 537
    Height = 169
    ControlCollection = <
      item
        Control = upperPanel
        AlignBottomWithPanel = False
        AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel = True
        AlignLeftWithPanel = False
        AlignRightWithPanel = False
        AlignTopWithPanel = True
        AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel = False
      end
      item
        Control = collapseButton
        AlignBottomWithPanel = False
        AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel = False
        AlignLeftWithPanel = False
        AlignRightWith = upperPanel
        AlignRightWithPanel = False
        AlignTopWithPanel = False
        AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel = False
        Below = upperPanel
      end>
    Align = alTop
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    TabOrder = 0
    DesignSize = (
      537
      169)
    object upperPanel: TPanel
      Left = 143
      Top = 3
      Width = 250
      Height = 41
      Align = alTop
      Caption = 'upperPanel'
      Color = clSilver
      ParentBackground = False
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object collapseButton: TButton
      Left = 359
      Top = 50
      Width = 34
      Height = 25
      Anchors = []
      Caption = '^'
      TabOrder = 1
    end
  end
end
```